# Function and array of strings using swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Good day everyone I want to create a function that takes an array of strings and return an array, sorted from shortest to longest but I'm getting a terminated by signal 4 error. I'm using an online swift compiler on my windows laptop if that somehow matters.

here's the code I wrote:

```
var siliconvalley = ["Google", "Apple", "Microsoft"]
var elementamount: Int = siliconvalley.count
var newarray: [String] = [] //new array created to store the newly sorted array
var a = siliconvalley[0].count // this variable was created to count the letters of the first string in the array

var temporary: String = "" // this was created to store the largest string so that I can use it to append the new array 

func longestelement () -> [String] {
    repeat {
        if siliconvalley[1].count > a {
            print (siliconvalley[1])
            temporary = siliconvalley[1]
            siliconvalley.remove(at:1)
    
        }
        else if siliconvalley[2].count > a {
            print (siliconvalley[2])
            temporary = siliconvalley[2]
            siliconvalley.remove(at:2)
        }
        else {
            print (siliconvalley[0])
            temporary = siliconvalley[0]
            siliconvalley.remove(at:0)
        }
        newarray.append(temporary)
        elementamount = elementamount - 1
    } while elementamount > 0 
    return newarray
}
print (longestelement())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know swift has built-in sorting?  You can do:

```
siliconvalley.sorted(by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```

and then if you just want the longest use `.last`

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this! But could you suggest a fix for the error I'm having? Just curious to know where I went wrong with the way I approached it

Comment: @TarequeRobinson Several problems.  You compare to `a` but you never uodate `a` if the first element in the array changes.

Comment: @TarequeRobinson The comparison logic is also flawed.  If you had string in the array with lengths of 1, 3 and 5 on the first pass through the loop 3 > 1 so it gets appended to newArray.   Next time though the loop 5 > 1 so gets appended to newArray.  Then finally 1 gets appended.  So you get a return array of [3-character string, 5 character string, 1 character string].  The problem is your first if just compares value of a (which you want to be length of element 0, and sometimes will be) against the second element, not against al elements.

Answer (score 0):

here's the issue:

```
while elementamount > 0
```

Consider rechecking the code for possible illogical loop termination condition.

P.S: `elementamount` is always greater than 0.

Comment: I changed the while loop condition to ` while elementamount != 0 ` my thinking was that since each time the loop runs the value of  ` elementamount ` would be decreasing so the condition would eventually be false and end the loop but it isn't working for me. I'm getting the same error